# Why could Twitter Streaming API limitation track number go up and down?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api, rate-limiting

I'm trying to track how many tweets are sent in real time for some topic. Therefor I am satisfied with counting incoming tweets and adding the value of `limit` messages to my counter. **But** despite descriptions in the [official API](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/messages-types#limit_notices) I get numbers of missed messages like:

`2, 5, 7, 4, 13, 15, 11, 20, 23, 17, ...`

So after all they are going up, but they fluctuate.

I use [Twitter4J library](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) to retrieve twitter data. I would be very thankful for some hints...

Answer (score 0):

Over at the Twitter forum there are a few threads ([1](https://twittercommunity.com/t/non-monotonic-rate-limit-message-counts/22175/2), [2](https://twittercommunity.com/t/why-are-track-values-in-limit-notices-out-of-order-and-how-to-interpret-them/35729/8)) pointing out exactly what you are experiencing.

The Twitter staff has yet to advise us on how to make sense of the fluctuating tracking counts. My guess is that behind the scenes there are multiple counters that are being reported. Who knows.

Comment: Thanks. Though you posted twice the same link! ;)
This would be really interesting to know how to work with these data! :/

Comment: Links are now fixed. Thanks!